# Piping mp4 video file to v4l2 devices lowers the frame rate in ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, v4l2

I'm trying to play a 10fps video file on multiple v4l2 loopback devices. 
Although the following command outputs the video on the video devices, it does not maintain the framerate. The framerate (and speed), as reported by ffmpeg, starts from 1-2 fps (speed ~ 0.100x-0.200x) and moves towards 1fps and 1x speed, but never reaches them. Depending on the number of outputs, it might settle on something like 9.5 fps and 0.950x speed if I only use 2-3 v4l2 devices, or ~6fps and 0.600x speed if I use all 8 devices.

What causes this behavior and how can I fix it?

```
ffmpeg -i ~/video.mp4 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video2 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video3 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video4 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video5 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video6 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video7 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video8 \
```

Comment: Show full log. Consider using the [tee muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#tee).

Comment: That was a great pointer, thanks @llogan. 
I improved it to ```ffmpeg -re -f video4linux2 -video_size 1280x960 -input_format yuyv422 -i /dev/video1 -c:v rawvideo -f tee -map 0:v "[f=v4l2]/dev/video2|[f=v4l2]/dev/video3|[f=v4l2]/dev/video4|[f=v4l2]/dev/video6|[f=v4l2]/dev/video7|[f=v4l2]/dev/video8" -vf tpad=start_duration=10 -f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video5``` and it's much better. Any way I can do the `tpad` inside the tee muxer, and also avoid repeating `[f=v4l2]` part?
Also, please add your comment as an answer so I accept it.

Comment: Sure, but it will be easier/more accurate if you first show the complete log from your most recent command. You can [edit] your question and include it there.

Comment: Is `/dev/video5` the only one requiring tpad?

Comment: Yes, that's the only one. Sure, I can add a log tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell ffmpeg you want it to run in real time by adding the `-re` parameter before `-I`. Otherwise it will go as fast as it can.

```
ffmpeg -re -i ~/video.mp4 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video2 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video3 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video4 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video5 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video6 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video7 \
-f v4l2 -r 10 -pix_fmt yuyv422 /dev/video8
```

Comment: `-re` ilimits the speed at which ffmpeg main thread calls av_read_frame or reads from input packet fifo, when demuxer is in separate thread. The issue here is slow processing, due to multiple (redundant) encoding.